# Cluster Resource fails every 8 hours for SQL AG

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover-cluster-instance

Every ~8 hours, I receive the error below in my Windows Cluster events. During this same time connections to SQL server are being lost.  I am struggling to find any resources that help determine what the issue is and possible solutions.

One thing I have noticed is that the Windows Cluster Name is the same as the AG name and I wonder if there is a conflict.

*Cluster resource 'SQLCluster' of type 'SQL Server Availability Group' in clustered role 'SQLCluster' failed.*

*The Cluster service failed to bring clustered role 'SQLCluster' completely online or offline. One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the availability of the clustered role.*

The error is only generated for the current primary node.

Answer (score 5):

> One thing I have noticed is that the Windows Cluster Name is the same as the AG name and I wonder if there is a conflict.

There is no issue there. If there were, it wouldn't come online in the first place. The AG name is a cluster resource which doesn't have anything external associated with it, it's entirely internal to the cluster. The cluster name is backed by the CNO which does have a computer AD object (if AD integrated) and DNS entries associated with it.

> Cluster resource 'SQLCluster' of type 'SQL Server Availability Group' in clustered role 'SQLCluster' failed.

> I am struggling to find any resources that help determine what the issue is and possible solutions.

1. Look at the cluster log. This can be achieved via powershell, `get-clusterlog`, and I'd add `-uselocaltime` so that the time values aren't in UTC... unless that's your thing.
2. Look at the SQL Server errorlog.

> Every ~8 hours, I receive the error below in my Windows Cluster events. During this same time connections to SQL server are being lost.

If it's every 8 hours, there is something in your environment which is triggered on a fairly accurate schedule. If this is a VM, this can be things like backups, migrations, etc., which will *not* be visible inside of the guest.

You'll need to look at the above-mentioned logs in order to diagnose what is happening, or at least get the next bread crumb.